# How does git deal with identical branch names from two different remote repo?

Tags: git, git-remote, git-checkout

If I set up two remote using **git remote add** for a repo, and the two repo contain a branch with the same name.  How does git know which branch of which repo I intend to use when I switch to it using **git checkout**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How does git know which branch of which repo I intend to use when I switch to it using git checkout?

It doesn't. Typically, if there is ambiguity, such as in this situation where both remotes ("origin" and "upstream2") have a `devel` branch:

```
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/devel
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/upstream2/devel
  remotes/upstream2/master
```

If I simply try to `git checkout devel` I get:

```
$ git checkout devel
error: pathspec 'devel' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

I need to be explicit:

```
$ git checkout -b devel remotes/upstream2/devel
Branch devel set up to track remote branch devel from upstream2 by rebasing.
Switched to a new branch 'devel'
```

Compare this to the situation where I have only a single remote:

```
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/devel
  remotes/origin/master
```

And then:

```
$ git checkout devel
Branch devel set up to track remote branch devel from origin by rebasing.
Switched to a new branch 'devel'
```

Comment: (NB: this behavior is true for git version 2.4.0)