# Branch name clashes when pushing

Tags: git, git-push, git-clone, git-checkout, git-fetch

**What I think I know**

When I clone or fetch from a remote repository, the name of the remote is prefixed to the names of the branches imported from this remote.
For instance, if the remote is called `origin` in my repository, then after cloning the remote's `master` branch is called `origin/master` in my repository.

This behavior makes sure that there are never name clashes between imported branches to branches that already exist in my repository (whether they were created locally or imported from other repositories).

**What I don't know (i.e. my question)**

When I push to a remote repository, is my repository name prefixed (in the remote repository) to the names of the branches that get pushed?

If not, how are branch name clashes avoided?

Comment: Branch name clashes *aren't* avoided, as you can find out by creating branches with the same name in two places and trying to push both to the same remote. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31631726/how-does-git-deal-with-identical-branch-names-from-two-different-remote-repo and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359978/why-has-git-allowed-me-to-create-two-branches-with-the-same-name for more on separate local and remote branches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I think I know
>
> When I clone or fetch from a remote repository, the name of the remote is **prefixed** to the names of the branches imported from this remote.
>
> For instance, if the remote is called origin in my repository, then after cloning  the remote's master branch is called `origin/master` in my repository.

Its not exactly like this.
When you clone a git repository git you get **reference** to all the branches but only master is checked out

[image]

Every time you checkout a branch git add a **track** branch to it

[image]

> When I push to a remote repository, is my repository name prefixed (in the remote repository) to the names of the branches that get pushed?

Whenever you type push git use an internal mechanism called [**`refspec`**](https://www.git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec)

> **[`refspec`](https://www.git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec)**
>
> The format of the **refspec** is an optional `+`, followed by `<src>:<dst>`, where `<src>` is the pattern for references on the remote side and `<dst>` is where those references will be written locally.
> **The + tells Git to update the reference even if it isn’t a fast-forward.**

More reading:
https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/refs-and-the-reflog#refspecs